# tipTip works on 'second' hover after ajax request using tiptip and jquery on()

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, calendar, tiptip

I'm using wordpress + ajax calendar future post plugin ( http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-plugin-ajax-calendar-with-future-posts/ ) + tiptip plugins http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin. I've managed to get them working together, though the tiptip only works on the 2nd hover - What I mean is when you first time hover element after ajax request tiptip doesn't show. I use the calendar as a widget on my home page.

This is the way I activate tiptip.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $("#wp-calendar").on("hover"," td a", function(){ $(this).tipTip(); });
...
});
```

it works fine for the initial load if I use

```
$("#wp-calendar td a").tipTip();
```

, but it disappears after ajax request.

The question is how do I get the tiptip to show the way it supposed to show: on the 'first hover', mouseenter, mouseover etc. I've tried all of those events. AKA: How do I get the first piece of code to work properly.

I've tried to find an answer, which got me to the stage I'm now. It's beyond my 'now-skill' to get pass this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well i think that if you make an AJAX call you and recreate the elemenets you must re-initialize the plugin. I think you should put this call

```
 $("#wp-calendar td a").tipTip();
```

in the success handler of the ajax call AFTER the new elements have been inserted. If you can't control the ajax call try using ajaxComplete()

```
$('body').ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
     $("#wp-calendar td a").tipTip();
});
```

If you do this, i think you can take away this call:

```
$("#wp-calendar").on("hover"," td a", function(){ $(this).tipTip(); });
```

because you already have reapplied the plugin.

Comment: ajax runs on:

onclick="microAjax(this.href + \'?ajax=true\',show_micro_ajax); return false"', $text );

Comment: I actually tried to do this and it didn't work for the first time, however with your encouragement to try it again I called  

    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#wp-calendar td a").tipTip();
    });}

AFTER 
    show_micro_ajax(response){document.getElementById('wp-calendar').innerHTML=response;  

and it worked.

Comment: @KamilZawadzki i think that you just need to run `jQuery("#wp-calendar td a").tipTip();`  after `show_micro_ajax` to make it work, no need for `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ )`