# TipTip only working on second hover after ajaxpost

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

**Situation:**

My tooltips show up on my page. Opening my fancybox works. Doing the ajax post from that fancybox works.
But my tooltips don't work in that fancybox. And they don't work after my ajax post.

I tried to reinitialize TipTip with the callbacks of fancybox.

**EDIT**
Title changes
So I found a way to let it run on the second hover after post but not on first hover.

I also found some explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386176/tiptip-works-on-second-hover-after-ajax-request-using-tiptip-and-jquery-on) but it still didn't fix my problem. Probably doing it wrong.

**EDIT 2**
Tootip in fancybox working use afterShow only.

**Changes**

added this in $(function () { so that it calls this function instead of initTipTip.

```
 $(".tooltip").live('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).tipTip();

});
```

Code of my function that does the post thing and closes my fancybox.

> ```
> var reservation = MakeReservation();
> var oldDateSplit = $("#resDate").val().split('/');
> var newDateSplit = $("#dateEditReservation").val().split('/');
> var oldDate = new Date(oldDateSplit[2], oldDateSplit[1] - 1, oldDateSplit[0]);
> var newDate = new Date(newDateSplit[2], newDateSplit[1] - 1, newDateSplit[0]);
> var time = $("#txtTime");
> $.ajax({
>     url: ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/CheckSettings'),
>     data: "JSONString=" + reservation + "&hasJavaScriptMethod=" + true
> }).done(function (data) {
>
>     if (data.length == 0 || oldDate.getTime() == newDate.getTime()) {
>         $.fancybox.close();
>         var id = $("#reservationId").val();
>
>
>         $("#reservationList").load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/reservationList',
> ```
>
> function () { initTipTip(); }));
>               $("#reservationDetail").load(ResolveUrl('~/Reservation/DetailInfo',
>   function () { initTipTip(); }), { reservationId: id });
>               $("#reservationList").on("hover", " .tooltip", function () { $(this).tipTip(); });
>           }
>           else {
>               $(".errorDiv").removeClass("hidden");
>               $(".errorDiv").html(data);
>               $(".btnReservations").removeAttr('disabled');
>           }
>
> ```
> });
> ```
>
> **NEW**
>           $(".tooltip").live('mouseover', function () {
>           $(this).tipTip();
>
> ```
> });
> ```
>
> }

**Still the same as before the edit.**

Code initialization for TipTip

```
function initTipTip () {

   $(".tooltip").tipTip();


}
```

Code of fancybox

```
function openFancy() {

    $("a.inline").fancybox({
        'type': 'ajax',
        'afterShow': function () {
             return initTipTip();
          }
    });

    $("a.inlineBlockedDate").fancybox({
        'type': 'ajax',
        'ajax': { cache: false },
        'afterShow': function () {
            return initTipTip();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this.

So I used my .live in $(function(){ like in my question but I did not use ".tooltip" here but the table itself. I also use initTipTip here instead of $(this).tipTip();
So this solves the Tooltip from TipTip.

**Explanation:** This is because the tooltip.live only gets triggered on first hover and not when the table 'refreshes'. So now you add that event on that refresh of the table
Correct me if I'm wrong here.

So no need for any other .tiptip stuff or InitTipTip then in $(function(){

```
 $("#reservationList").live('mouseover', function () {
    initTipTip();

});
```

I hope your problem gets solved with this question.